# How to remove the ribbon and command bar in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ribbon

I've tried removing the ribbon bar according to [this](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-ribbon-in-windows-10-explorer/) guide, using Winaero's Remove Ribbon tool. Instead of just removing it, it replaces the ribbon with the command bar, containing tools that I either have no use for or  that I can access by right clicking inside the folder. Google gives me no answers so I come to you.

How can I remove the ribbon in Windows 10 without replacing it with the command bar, or anything else for that matter?

Comment: You would have to replace File Explorer all together or use some other third-party software that changes the behavior of File Explorer.  I suggest getting use to be designed it will be around for awhile.  You can also use a legacy version of Windows

Comment: Classic shell (http://www.classicshell.net/) has this. It is a program that can turn your windows startmenu into one that appeared in windows xp or 7, but they also have a program that can turn the explorer into one that looked from xp or 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OldNewExplorer to add Command Bar, and then you can follow this guide:

https://www.askvg.com/how-to-make-folder-band-auto-hidden-in-windows-vista/

and replace `FolderBandStyle` in the OldNewExplorer's `UIFILE`s: `OldNewExplorer32.dll` and `OldNewExplorer64.dll`:

Using the ResourceHacker, find the lines:

> <style resid="FolderBandStyle">

and

> <style resid="CPLFolderBandStyle">

after them put:

> <Element padding="rect(0rp,0rp,0rp,-44rp)"/>

Compile & save. and then "Install" in OldNewExplorer.

Here screenshot of what it will become:

[image]

I can confirm that it works on W10-1909-18363.535.

Answer (score -1):

To remove the Ribbon you can use the tools Riddon Disabler or OldNewExplorer.
Then to hide the command bar you need to edit shellstyle.dll of your theme.
[Here](https://www.askvg.com/how-to-make-folder-band-auto-hidden-in-windows-vista/) is an how to.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please [edit] your answer to include the relevant information here. Thanks